# How to run a postgres command in python script and write it into a file?

Tags: shell, python, postgresql

```
cmd1 = 'psql -h hello.com -p 5433 -U hell_ro-d hello-c \"COPY (SELECT info1,info2,info3,info4 FROM logs_info WHERE info1 > \''+str(timing)+'\' and info1 < clock_timestamp() ORDER BY info1 desc limit 100) TO STDOUT With CSV HEADER\"  > filedetails.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run your shell command with `os.system`:

```
$ python -c 'from os import system; system("cat >/dev/stderr <<<\"shelly stuff\"")'
shelly stuff
```

Comment: Actually I am accessing a linux server remotely using paramiko, os.sytem might not work for the same. Would it?

Comment: it would run where the python was running.  I think that means no. Paramiko is for just that, isn't it? You should update your question with the relevant details of what you're doing now